Disabling datetime changes in Highstock V2.1.9
I'm dealing with a legacy web application utilizing Highstock.js v2.1.9 to visualize time series data in stock charts. The issue I'm facing is that the datetime values get adjusted based on the user's desktop timezone settings. For instance, on a Windows system, altering the timezone in settings results in all chart time values shifting accordingly.
We handle datetime value adjustments server-side, depending on the user's UTC offset. Consequently, we want to prevent Highstock from modifying our data based on client timezones. Given the age of v2.1.9, I've had difficulty finding relevant API documentation. I've experimented with time properties like useUTC and timezone, but they don't seem to preserve our data unaltered regardless of client timezones.
In summary, how can I configure Highstock v2.1.9 to avoid modifying our datetime values according to the client's timezone?

In order to make it work, you can set the global.useUTC option to false, and  the date timestamps shouldn't change based on user timezone.
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6xfz3chr/
Reference: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/4dcfd548931e9fa5578530cf372bc2ed42162fd5/js/parts/Options.js#L21-L26

Thanks, I do have global.useUTC set to false, but my application seems to still change x-axis values based on the system timezone. I know this is client-side as this change occurs without a page refresh. Could it be another property causing this?

In this case you can try using getTimezoneOffset() method, which returns the timezoneOffset based on timestamps and given time zone. This approach requires including the moment.js library.
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8o1ntu4v/
Reference:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/4dcfd548931e9fa5578530cf372bc2ed42162fd5/samples/highcharts/global/gettimezoneoffset/demo.js
